# Merging two branches from SVN in IntelliJ without using command prompt

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

How can I merge two branches from SVN in IntelliJ?

One of the branches is a branch I created but I want some of the classes and xml files that were made by another team that is branched off from the trunk. I am wondering how I can do this without using the command prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* run `svn merge` via IntelliJ IDEA without using the command prompt. Just open a versioned project and go to **VCS | Merge from**.

I guess that you may find these docs helpful:

- [Integrating Changes To/From Feature Branches](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/integrating-changes-to-from-feature-branches.html)
- [Integrating Changes to Branch](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/integrating-changes-to-branch.html)

Comment: it's in Version `Control tool window` -> `Subversion Working Copies Information tab` now (updated in references sources).